# how do i rotate an object in particular angle by importing the values from a csv file and animating at different frame time?

Tags: animation, import, csv

I want to rotate an object at different angles at different frame time by importing the values of angle from a csv file. the file contains a number of angles which i want to allocate as keyframes at diffenet times.

Comment: Please show you completed work in Blender with a screen capture at minimum. Please state your months/years of experience with Blender, Python programming language and Blender API. You may also wish to show some of your file data for clarity. Its useful to know if there are 8 rows of data or 8888

Comment: If you have already read in the file please show your Python. Typically in this scenario .. Step 1 is to read in a file .... or just copy and paste the data in the blender text file window, if this is compatible with your needs. Step 2 is to use the data. So by many peoples reasoning these could be two separate questions. This is a relatively small programming project.

Comment: Sometimes people view these requests as a tutorial request either in Blender or Python or Blender API. Other times people randomly provide you with a complete solution. At BSE your typical question should not be a tutorial request. We want to see some of your completed work to show your effort